# How to verify a QFile is open?

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to make a log file for an application.
I made a function to create it:

```
void MainWindow::Logs(){

    QString nomlog = "log.txt";
    logtxt = new QFile(nomlog);
    logtxt->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    QTextStream out(logtxt);
       out << "This file is generated by Qt\n";

    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("log.txt"));

}
```

This part works fine, the file is created, with the wanted text.

But the problem comes up when I want to write in that same file, through another function. I tried to make a condition to verify is the file is open, if not an error message shows up:

```
void MainWindow::testconnect(){
    logtxt = new QFile("log.txt");
    if(logtxt->isOpen()){
        QTextStream out(logtxt);
           out << "Le fichier log a été ouvert !\n";
           }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Echec","Le fichier log n'existe pas");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the message always show up, even when I activated the first action that should have created and opened the log file.

I hope it was clear, sorry if it wasn't.
Could you help me out with this please?
Thanks you!

Comment: But you're creating a second QFile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create a second QFile in your `testconnect` function. Try storing `logtxt` as a member variable instead of recreating it all the time. That way you will be testing the same file to see if it's open.

Comment: Tank you ! I declared it instead in the mainWindow, and now it works, it was really a stupid mistake... Took me about an hour to fix it, thanks !

Comment: Glad to help! If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.